# I am trying slicing but I have the following error message: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am trying slicing but I have the following error message: `slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

```
descriptors = numpy.fft.fftshift(descriptors)
center_index = len(descriptors) / 2
descriptors = descriptors[center_index - degree / 2:center_index + degree / 2]
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-4-ebf374694eeb>", line 7, in truncate_descriptor
    center_index - degree / 2:center_index + degree / 2]

Comment: You using  `center_index - degree / 2` as an index. Doe it always give you an integer?

Answer (score 2):

In python3 you need to use `//` for floor division unlike python2 where it was just `/`:

```
import numpy as np

descriptors = [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4., -5., -4., -3., -2., -1.]
descriptors = np.fft.fftshift(descriptors)
print(descriptors)
center_index = len(descriptors) // 2
degree = 4
descriptors = descriptors[center_index - degree // 2 : center_index + degree // 2]
print(descriptors)
```

**Output:**

```
[-5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
[-2. -1.  0.  1.]
```